# Combined file HTML + CSS for opening in browser

Tags: html, css, file-format

I was wondering **if there is a file format around** where I can put (one or multiple) .css and (one or multiple) .html files, for example as a .zip (or similar) file AND your favourite browser can recognize it and opens it as a sort of static local "web page".

My use case would be to create html reports of some program execution, style it with a standardized css file and upload it on a cloud service, such that anyone with access can view it direcly in the browser.

I know a litte about html and css, but not enough to answer this question myself.
And "combine html and css" is not searchable on the web, so I'm asking you.

I'm not looking for a solution which bakes everything into one file.
I'm also not looking for an unzipped version of this (a folder), since that is not uploadable to most cloud storages I am aiming for.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such format. The best you can do is bundle your css at the bottom of your page with `<style> CSS GOES HERE </style>` tags. The HTML file remains the same, and the CSS is bundled in it.

Comment: When you save page in Internet Explorer, it offers to save HTML and related files separately or together. When you choose a single file, it saves it as MHTML - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML, although not all browser may correctly recognize this format. If you create HTML yourself, the best you can do is to use `<style>` and `<script>` tags inside HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Anomymous! I think this is what I was looking for. And chromium edge (modern browser) is also mentioned. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no file format for that, but what you can do is create a folder in your htdocs or public folder and add all your `.css` and `.html` files in there. Then access it in `localhost/yourfolder` or if you are using a host `http://yourdomain.com/yourfolder`. For your HTML files to display the style correctly, they should be linked with the `.css` files or with the style  inside each `.html` file between `<style></style>` tags in the `<head>` section.

You will see something like this, where you and others can preview and navigate through all HTML and CSS files.

[image]

**Note:** I've never done this on a host only on localhost, if you are using a host you will probably need to create permisions to access this folder, in that case contact your host so they can explain.